# AES decryption on Flutter not working, what encoding?

Tags: swift, flutter, encryption, aes

I am encrypting a file in Swift with way (using Apple CryptoKit), in AES-256:

```
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonPath)
    let skey = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)
    let dataSkey = skey.withUnsafeBytes {Data(Array($0)).base64EncodedString()}
    print(dataSkey) // DeDGtpqvojYL32bIsEsaaXZITjJp4bAW7aQgtVYARO0=
    let aes = try AES.GCM.seal(jsonData, using: skey)
    try aes.combined!.write(to: encryptedPath)
    // UPLOAD FILE (encryptedPath) TO FIREBASE STORAGEs
```

I am then trying to decrypt the file in Flutter (.dart) with [this](https://pub.dev/packages/steel_crypt) pub  this way:

```
import 'package:steel_crypt/steel_crypt.dart';

final File tmpFile = File(//path of file downloaded from storage firebase);
var aesEncrypter = AesCrypt('DeDGtpqvojYL32bIsEsaaXZITjJp4bAW7aQgtVYARO0=', 'gcm', 'pkcs7');
String decrypted = aesEncrypter.decrypt(tmpFile.readAsStringSync());
print(decrypted);
```

But I always get this error:

> "FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8',
>   path =*path*.file.json"

What am I doing wrong? I tried to encode the file from swift in base64 and read it again in flutter with base64 without success.

Comment: Your key looks like it's encoded in base64, so wouldn't you use the `Key.fromBase64` constructor?

Comment: Also, doesn't CryptoKit only support GCM? You'll need a GCM implementation in Dart.

Comment: thank you for the comments, I edited my code and now using GCM, but still that result

Comment: You're trying to read a CryptoKit sealed box as a string! Surely that's not going to work. Is the internal format of sealed box documented? Also, you aren't passing the IV to the decrypt method, but that's not the immediate problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332076/cross-platform-aes-encryption-between-ios-and-kotlin-java-using-apples-cryptokit seems to imply that the binary form of `combined` will be `nonce || ciphertext || tag`. If you aren't familiar with how CryptoKit works under the hood, you might want to use the older, lower-level Apple crypto apis where you are more likely to find interoperability examples.

Comment: If I encrypt a json, containing a String, I should be able to decrypt it after and read it as a String. I tried the older one, but didn't find the GCM of it.

Comment: yes, but you are trying to read the binary encrypted sealed box as a string here: `tmpFile.readAsStringSync()`. Presumably the file contents is binary.

Comment: thank you, again, for the reply. It's asking for a String as you can see here (line 97) https://github.com/AKushWarrior/steel_crypt/blob/master/lib/src/aes.dart

Comment: but it's expecting base64 encoded binary - because it immediately decodes it:         `var localInput = base64.decode(encrypted);` Where are you separating the nonce from the ciphertext?