AES/GCM/NoPadding encryption in Swift iOS (min deployment 12.1) doesn't produce expected ciphertext length
I'm implementing AES/GCM/NoPadding encryption in Swift for iOS with a minimum deployment target of 12.1. I'm trying to achieve similar functionality as my Java code below:
Cipher cipherAes = initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
byte[] encryptedMessageByte = cipherAes.doFinal(messageBytes);

byte[] cipherByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + salt.length + encryptedMessageByte.length)
        .put(iv)
        .put(salt)
        .put(encryptedMessageByte)
        .array();

In Swift, I've written the following code:
let gcm = GCM(iv: iv.bytes, additionalAuthenticatedData: nil, tagLength: tagLength)
let aes = try AES(key: key.bytes, blockMode: gcm, padding: .noPadding)
let encryptedMessage = try aes.encrypt(message.bytes)
let cipherData = Data(iv) + Data(salt) + Data(encryptedMessage)

However, the length of encryptedMessage in Swift differs from encryptedMessageByte in Java. I expected both to produce ciphertext of similar lengths.
Assurance:
I'm sure that the lengths of key, iv, and salt are the same in both Java and Swift implementations.
Question:
Are there any additional configurations or parameters needed for AES/GCM/NoPadding encryption in Swift to match the behavior in Java?

does this post answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332076/cross-platform-aes-encryption-between-ios-and-kotlin-java-using-apples-cryptokit/61345165#61345165

In the Java code, ciphertext and GCM authentication tag are concatenated by default; in the CryptoSwift code, both are handled detached by default.
To make the CryptoSwift code compatible with Java code, either ciphertext and tag can be explicitly concatenated:
...
let gcm = GCM(iv: iv.bytes, additionalAuthenticatedData: nil, tagLength: tagLength, mode: .detached) // detached is the default
let aes = try! AES(key: key.bytes, blockMode: gcm, padding: .noPadding)
let encryptedMessage = try! aes.encrypt(message.bytes)
let tag = gcm.authenticationTag!
let cipherData = Data(iv) + Data(salt) + Data(encryptedMessage) + Data(tag) // concatenate explicitly
...

or encryption is done in combined mode, whereby ciphertext and tag are implicitly concatenated as well:
...
let gcm = GCM(iv: iv.bytes, additionalAuthenticatedData: nil, tagLength: tagLength, mode: .combined) // apply combined mode
let aes = try! AES(key: key.bytes, blockMode: gcm, padding: .noPadding)
let encryptedMessageTag = try! aes.encrypt(message.bytes)
let cipherData = Data(iv) + Data(salt) + Data(encryptedMessageTag)
...

See also the AES-GCM examples in the documentation
